# How To Remove stdClass Object IN Codeigniter PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter

How to remove stdClass object in PHP?

**Controller:**

`$detail['shipping'] = $this->Mymodel->Tcs_get_data('shipment_master');` 
Here is my `ARRAY`

**View:**

Using `print_r($shipping);`

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [sc_id] => 1 [sc_amount_s] => 0 [sc_amount_e] => 4999 [sc_charges] => 150 [sc_status] => 0 [sc_delete] => 0 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [sc_id] => 2 [sc_amount_s] => 5000 [sc_amount_e] => 9999 [sc_charges] => 100 [sc_status] => 0 [sc_delete] => 0 ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [sc_id] => 4 [sc_amount_s] => 10000 [sc_amount_e] => 99999 [sc_charges] => 0 [sc_status] => 0 [sc_delete] => 0 ) )
```

Comment: Writing everything in CAPS is a __bad idea__.

Comment: use `result_array()` instead of `result()` in model

Comment: Please don't shout

Answer (score 0):

You can use `result_array()` instead of `result()` in your model query OR do this:

```
$shippingArray = [];
foreach ($shipping as $key => $value) {
    array_push($shippingArray, $value)
}
print_r($shippingArray);
```

By putting all values in other array

OR you can use current array object into your view LIKE:

```
foreach ($shipping as $key => $value) {
    // Here you can use $value as you want..
    // echo '<tr><td>'. $value->sc_amount_e .'</td></tr>'; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have there is an associative array of objects.

`stdClass` denotes an object that is accessed via a pointer `->`.

`$shipping[0]->sc_id` is how to access a `stdClass` object in an array, whereas in an associative array without objects it is `$shipping[0]['sc_id']`.

**If you wish to use purely arrays then you need to stick to `result_array()` and `row_array()`.**

To be clear, although you may see `stdClass` in a `print_r` it isn't "visible" as a string and only denotes it is an object.

Answer (score 0):

In controller write this code,

```
$temp = $this->Mymodel->Tcs_get_data('shipment_master');
$detail['shipping'] = json_decode(json_encode($temp), true); // true is for making it array
```